# Properly loading JQuery on Rails (object has no method)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a course posted at http://schneems.com/ut-rails.  Here is the app I am working with: https://github.com/schneems/ruby_javascript_data_viz.git.

I am using Rails 3.2.6 and Ruby version 2.0.0p247.

I have only cloned this file to my desktop, installed the bundle, and set up the database.  When I use the console (Chrome) to see if JQuery is working, I get this error:

```
> $('body').hide();
  Type Error:  Object #<HTMLBodyElement> has no method 'hide'
```

When I view the page source to see if JQuery is loading, I can see this line:

```
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, I don't see anything for JQuery.  What am I missing here?

I have searched for this issue, and have found many similar questions, but I can't seem to find anything to get me going.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that jquery plugin is loaded and the document is ready before using hide() function.

Wrap this code in

```
$(function()
{
    $('body').hide();
}
```

and try.

Comment: Thanks Lavixu.  I was able to get it working by adding this in my application.html.erb file:  <%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" %>.  However, I'm not sure that is what you meant by making sure the plugin is loaded.

Comment: Also, is it not a good practice to put that code in the application.html.erb file?

Comment: @RyanLennberg Yes, that's what i meant by JQuery being loaded. As said, it is a good practice to keep all common plugins like jquery, highcharts in application.html.erb file so that it is loaded for all the files.